# How Can I Write A Code To Automatically Change Registry Values?

Tags: c++, c, windows, registry

I'm relatively new to coding (even though I've taken a few classes on it) and picked up a job working IT at the library on campus. I do Windows Updates on the computers and come across an error that requires me to alter the registry value of the Windows Update Service.  I would like to write a code to do that for me automatically, because it is rather time consuming to alter the registry on five hundred computers. Where do I start? Is it even possible?

To make the changes, I open:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Software
Policies
Microsoft
Windows
WindowsUpdate
AU
UseWUServer (this is where I change the value to 0)

Comment: Since you specified C/C++ you will need to use the Win32 API functions RegOpenKeyEx and RegSetValueEx.

Comment: Why not just use a registry file to do this?  Copy this into notepad and save it as a .reg file and run it on each machine  **DISCLAIMER:  PLEASE BACKUP YOUR REGISTRY BEFORE ATTEMPTING TO TEST THIS!**  

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU\UseWUServer]@="0"

Comment: You'd also get good answers to this sort of question on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

In Vista or greater than systems you will need elevated privileges to run anything that will modify the registry. Both answers above would work, I personally have found using power-shell scripts very powerful for this type of problem.